# How to get grid behavior columns dynamically?

Tags: yii2

I'm making a plugin system and I'm dynamically adding behaviors with relation to `Order` model. For example:

```
class OrderBehavior extends Behavior
{
    public function getOrderTrackNumber()
    {
        return $this->owner->hasOne(TrackNumber::class, ['order_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

At runtime I don't know which plugins (and therefore which behaviors) are activated.

How can I get all relation properties (in example `orderTrackNumber`) dynamically for render in `GridView` columns?

Comment: How your Gridview Columns displayed? Add griview also

Comment: At the moment I manually display all `Order` columns in `orders` table. There is nothing unusual there. All additional columns have their own tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`getBehaviors()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-component#getBehaviors()-detail) to get all active behaviors attached to model. At this point you should probably implement some interface for behaviors which may add new relations, so they will be able to provide list of defined relations - it may save you performance hell (browsing all behavior's methods and searching relations definitions may be slow and unreliable). For example:

```
interface BehaviorWithRelationsInterface {

    /**
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getRelationsNames(): array;
}
```

Then in model:

```
/**
 * @return string[]
 */
public function getAllRelationsNames(): array {
    $relations = [];
    foreach ($this->getBehaviors() as $behavior) {
        if ($behavior instanceof BehaviorWithRelationsInterface) {
            $relations = array_merge($relations, $behavior->getRelationsNames());
        }
    }

    // add relations defined directly in model
    $relations[] = 'user';

    return $relations;
}
```

If you don't miss anything, `getAllRelationsNames()` should return names of all relations defined in model.

Answer (score 0):

there's no built in method in yii2 that returns all relations of a model,

you can either check your attached behaviours via [behaviours()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-component#behaviors()-detail) method,
or, if you need a complete list, check via Reflection whether your getters and attached behaviors return an object that implements relation interface.